# Auto Create Bugs For A Target Milestone

Tags: bugzilla

Each time I create a new Target Milestone in Bugzilla, I have a set of bugs that I need to create and associate with that target (these are essentially all the same, and could be based on some kind of template).

These bugs represent a set of tasks that must be performed as part of every milestone.

**Is there a way to auto-create a set of bugs for each milestone that I create?**

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Bugzilla extension that hooks object_end_of_create http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/api/Bugzilla/Hook.html#object_end_of_create and specifically looks for the milestone object then create the needed bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that out and see how I get on.